# changing button text when a button is clicked on with in a listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-button

Hi hoping someone can help. I have a list view that displays various textviews,editviews and abutton on each row. I have used the getView

```
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {            
        View v = convertView;


           if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.catlistrow, null);

           }

           TextView pDesc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productlinerow);
           TextView pPack = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.productlinerow3);
           ImageView iThumbnail = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);
           final Button bAdd = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.SOCatLine);

            final EditText pOrdQty = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.SOQty);


           pDesc.setText(((HashMap<String,String>) getItem(position)).get("Column2")); 
           pPack.setText(((HashMap<String,String>) getItem(position)).get("Column3"));
           pOrdQty.setText(((HashMap<String,String>) getItem(position)).get("OrdQty"));
           String EanCode = ((HashMap<String,String>) getItem(position)).get("EANCode");
```

I then add a OnClickListner for the add button with in the getView

```
                bAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){          
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Object o = list.get(position);
            HashMap<String, String> map2 = (HashMap<String, String>)o;
            String b = map2.get("OrdQty");
            String sProdCode = map2.get("ProdCode");
            String ProdPrice = map2.get("ProdPrice");
            b = pOrdQty.getText().toString();

            int OrderQty = Integer.parseInt(b);

            //Check to see if add is pressed and qty zero
            if ( OrderQty == 0 )
            {
              OrderQty = 1;
              b = "1";

            }

            db.open();
            int iOrderNo = Integer.parseInt(OrderNo);


            // update line
            iLineNumber = iLineNumber + 1;
            int QtyCheck = db.createCATorderline(iOrderNo, iLineNumber,
                            sProdCode, ProdPrice, b,"P");


            bAdd.setText("Change"); 


            //Close the database
            db.close();



        }   

  });
```

The button text changes fine on the button i clicked on which is great. The problem im having is that if i scroll down every now and then i see the text has also changed on one of the buttons on the screen.

Can anyone help?

Thanks Neil

XML for the list view

```
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/Thumbnail"
android:layout_width="190px"
android:layout_height="200px"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:maxWidth="190px"
android:maxHeight="200px"
android:background="@null" />

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/productlinerow"
 android:textColor="#000000" 
 android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
 android:textSize="25dip"
 android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
 android:text="column1"
 android:layout_width="400dip" 
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Thumbnail"/> 


<TextView android:id="@+id/productlinerow3" 
 android:textColor="#000000" 
 android:textSize="25dip"
 android:text="column2" 
 android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"  
 android:layout_width="300dip" 
 android:layout_below="@+id/productlinerow"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Thumbnail"/>

<TextView
      android:id="@+id/qtylabel"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/productlinerow"
      android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/SOQty"
      android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
      android:layout_marginRight="30dip" 
      android:inputType="number" 
      android:editable="true"
      android:gravity="right" 

      android:text="Order Qty:"
      android:textSize="25dip" />

  <EditText
       android:id="@+id/SOQty"
       android:layout_width="100dip"
       android:layout_height="60dip"
       android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/SOCatLine"
       android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
       android:layout_below="@+id/productlinerow"
       android:text="1"
       android:maxLength="3"
       android:inputType="number"
       android:singleLine="true"
       android:textSize="25dip" 
       android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
       android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>

 <Button android:text="Add" android:background="@drawable/green_button"  

 android:id="@+id/SOCatLine"
 android:textSize="25dip" 
 android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
 android:layout_width="130dip" 
 android:layout_marginTop="30dip" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_below="@+id/productlinerow"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi i have readded it the main question

Comment: Could you post your main.xml as well?

Comment: So, the button is originally unchanged, but when you actually SCROLL, you see one of the button's text change? Or the button is originally out of view and you scroll down and it appears with different text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store the text of button in some kind of collection. As you can using HashMap here you can create one more Object of HashMap that will store the text of Button inside `getView()` using

```
bAdd.setText(((HashMap<String,String>) getItem(position)).get("btn_text"));
```

then you can `setTag()` the instance to use in `onClick()`

```
bAdd.setTag((HashMap<String,String>) getItem(position));
```

And then inside `onClick()` use `getTag()` to get the position of the Button.

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap<String,String>)v.getTag();
        map.put("btn_text", "Change");
        ((Button)v).setText(map.get("btn_text"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you initialize your bAdd button...nevermind I see it now.

I would check your XML file, two of your buttons probably have the same id.

Comment: Hi on the xml i only declare 1 button as it is a listvew. There is one button per row

Comment: Eclipse will give them all the same name by default. there is no way to know which one you will receive a reference to in findViewById(). JuiCe is correct.

Comment: Then everytime you change the button you have referenced, it changes all of them because they are the same button.

Comment: Hi on the first screen when i click on add it only changes the one button which is fine. The problem only appears when you scroll down

Comment: So, the button is originally unchanged, but when you actually SCROLL, you see one of the button's text change? Or the button is originally out of view and you scroll down and it appears with different text?

Comment: <ListView                                
  android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
  android:layout_below="@+id/MDividerstwo" 
  android:id="@+id/orderproductlistview"
  android:background="#FFFFFF" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_width="800dip"/>

Comment: i then have another one to handle the listview